# Wordpress - Redirect old HTML page to different site

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I need to redirect a page from an old, non wordpress site, that has been converted to a wordpress site and that page doesn't exist anymore to a different domain that is a wordpress site.

Original path: `http://example.com/exams.html`
New path: `https://example2.com/exams/`

This in my .htaccess file isn't doing anything at all and when I visit the page on the site it gives a 404 error because the exams.html file doesn't exist in wordpress and I guess the .htaccess file is being ignored?

```
RedirectMatch 301  http://example.com/exams.html https://example2.com/exams/
```

*Edited to add information
Site is on Host Gator shared hosting. 
domain.com is the main site for the account. 
domain.com resides in public_html/domain.com/ subfolder
domain2.com resides in public_html/domain2.com/ subfolder

Comment: Something that might help solve this issue is if we could redirect users to the ssl version of domain.com on any url, not just the base url, then I think some of the redirects with plugins we have would work properly.

Comment: You can also do this through your domain name purchase agent, you might not need to manually code it yourself.  I am assuming you still have control of both domains.

Comment: Perhaps something else is redirecting domain.com to domain2.com before your htaccess is considered. So I would add a redirect from http:// domain2.com /exams.html to https:// domain2.com /exams/ as well.

Comment: Your redirect rule looks fine based on the information you provided. Where did you include it in your `.htaccess`, and is your site runnig from a subfolder? One piece of advice I will give you however is *never* use a 301 redirect until you have confirmed it works - always test with 302 and only change to 301 once you know its right. Because now anything you try will be affected by the permanent redirect until your cache is cleared.

Comment: Important. Are you using apache, or nginx? In nginx there is no such thing as `.htaccess`.

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments and suggestions. The site is on a HostGator shared account. domain.com and domain2.com are both subfolders inside public_html. Like public_html/domain.com and public_html/domain2.com. Technically domain.com is the main domain for the hostgator account and required editing the .htaccess file in the public_html folder so it worked in the subfolder. I am not sure if it is using apahce or nginx, since it is shared I don't have access at that level I think.

Comment: @FluffyKitten what would you suggest if running the site from a subfolder?